# Java, how do I send an array between methods in java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, send

I have tried to send an array between two methods in java.  Can someone help me?

The code is:

```
package bubbeltest;

public class BubbelTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] list = new int[3];
        list[0]=5;
        list[1]=2;
        list[2]=3;
        sort(list);
    }
    public static int sort(list){


    }
}
```

Comment: If you use an IDE to write/correct the code for you it can change the code so it compiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static int sort(list)
```

should be

```
public static int sort(int[] list)
```

Java is a Strongly typed language. That means you need to specify the type of parameter you're sending. The type of a parameter also makes up part of the method signature, which is important in the way Java runs.

Answer (score 1):

```
package bubbeltest;

public class BubbelTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] list = new int[3];
        list[0]=5;
        list[1]=2;
        list[2]=3;
        sort(list);
    }
    public static int sort(int[] list){


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sort(int[] list){


}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your method signature to

```
public static int sort(int[] list){

}
```